# Automate VM Workstation

Tags: c#, automation, vmware, vmwaretasks

I am trying to automate VMWare Workstation, The function that I need to implements are:

1. Get all VM names
2. Stop VM
3. Start VM

#### Technology

I am using VMware Workstation 12 and .Net 2013 (C#)

What I have done after adding `Vestris.VMWareLib.dll` reference:

```
VMWareVirtualHost virtualHost = new VMWareVirtualHost();
// connect to a local (VMWare Workstation) virtual machine
virtualHost.ConnectToVMWareWorkstation();
// open an existing virtual machine
//VMWareVirtualMachine virtualMachine = virtualHost.Open(@"C:\Virtual 
Machines\xp\xp.vmx");

VMWareVirtualMachine virtualMachine = 
virtualHost.Open(@"C:\Users\tabish.mateen\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows 
7 x64\Windows 7 x64.vmx");


// power on this virtual machine
virtualMachine.PowerOn();
// wait for tools to launch
virtualMachine.WaitForToolsInGuest();
// login to the virtual machine
virtualMachine.LoginInGuest("Administrator", "password");
// run notepad
virtualMachine.RunProgramInGuest("notepad.exe", string.Empty);
// create a new snapshot
string name = "New Snapshot";
// take a snapshot at the current state
virtualMachine.Snapshots.CreateSnapshot(name, "test snapshot");
// power off
virtualMachine.PowerOff();
// find the newly created snapshot
VMWareSnapshot snapshot = virtualMachine.Snapshots.GetNamedSnapshot(name);
// revert to the new snapshot
snapshot.RevertToSnapshot();
// delete snapshot
snapshot.RemoveSnapshot();
```

I am getting error on second line when its trying to connect to work station.

#### Exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in
>   Vestris.VMWareLib.dll
>
> Additional information: Failed to connect:
>   serviceProviderType="Workstation" hostName="" hostPort=0 username=""
>   timeout=60

#### Inner Exception

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {6874E949-7186-4308-A1B9-D55A91F60728} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: Either that dll or dll's it uses need to be `regsvr32 Vestris.VMWareLib.dll`. Normally this is done by an setup.exe or an msi. You better find and run that. Also: is your app compiled for x64 or x86? Try x86 if you can.

Comment: I tried with x86 and x64 both have same error.

Comment: I tried to register it getting this error. "Was loaded but the entry-point DLLRegisterServer was not found.  Make sure that is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again

Comment: You need to run the setup that comes with those dlls as the dll itself doesn't have the required self-registration bits implemented.

Comment: There is no setup file, I downloaded the solution from here "https://github.com/dblock/vmwaretasks"

Comment: Yes there is, it is in the readme.md: *VMWare VIX. This is the SDK, obtained from http://www.vmware.com/download/sdk/vmauto.html. Version 1.6.2 or newer is required for VI support. Version 1.8.0 or newer is required for VMWare Player support.*

Comment: I already have VMWare Workstation 12 Player . In the second line there is "Either" word

Comment: OK, then still it looks like an registration issue with dll's on your box, not something we can fix in your code. Can you check if this: `reg query HKCR /s /f  {6874E949-7186-4308-A1B9-D55A91F60728}` doesn't return any results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151949/discussion-between-tabish-matin-and-rene).